# is it possible to run spark udf functions (mainly python) under docker?

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm using `pyspark` on `emr`. To simplify the setup of `python` libraries and dependencies, we're using `docker` images.

This works fine for general python applications (non spark), and for the spark driver (calling spark submit from within a docker image)

However, I couldn't find a method to make the workers run within a docker image (either the "full" worker, or just the `UDF` functions)

**EDIT**
Found a solution with beta EMR version, if there's some alternative with current (5.*) EMR versions it's still relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently yarn 3.2 supports this feature: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainers.html

and it expected to be available with EMR 6 (now in beta) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/run-spark-applications-with-docker-using-amazon-emr-6-0-0-beta/